# Mismatched types: expected somestruct<_,_> got somestruct<R,F>

Tags: rust, type-inference, type-mismatch

Could anyone please explain what does this error mean? That's literally the same struct.
Does it fail to infer R or F somehow and reports it this way?

```
src/demo.rs:113:51: 113:65 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut gfx_debug_draw::debug_renderer::DebugRenderer<_, _>`,
    found `&mut gfx_debug_draw::debug_renderer::DebugRenderer<R, F>`
(expected struct `gfx_debug_draw::debug_renderer::DebugRenderer`,
    found a different struct `gfx_debug_draw::debug_renderer::DebugRenderer`) [E0308]
src/demo.rs:113                 self.skeleton.draw(&global_poses, debug_renderer, settings.draw_labels);
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The offending line is here:
https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/skeletal_animation_demo/blob/master/src/demo.rs#L113
debug_renderer is defined here:
https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/skeletal_animation_demo/blob/master/src/demo.rs#L97
and the types come from impl here:
https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/skeletal_animation_demo/blob/master/src/demo.rs#L43

The function itself is here:
https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/skeletal_animation/blob/master/src/skeleton.rs#L66-L70

Rust 1.5 and 1.3, same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your project uses two different versions of `gfx_debug_draw` (hence `found a different struct gfx_debug_draw::debug_renderer::DebugRenderer`. It's the same struct, but from different versions of the same package.), probably because you specify one version in your `Cargo.toml` and one of your dependencies specifies a different version. You should check your `Cargo.lock` to see if that's true, and then make sure you use the same version of the crate everywhere.

Comment: Bingo. gfx_debug_draw 0.4.0 from dev_menu and 0.5.0 from several others. Fixed by replacing 0.4.0 with 0.5.0 in several files under ~/.cargo. I wonder if there's any better way to do this, other than fixing it upstream.

Also, not my project.

Comment: Ultimately this is [issue 22750](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22750), which has improved error message in the most recent nightly builds.